# React native Android Project Not starting in emulator

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

i just created a react native project on windows, using expo. After Creating the project i ran `npm start` and then `expo start` the next logical thing to do is to press the a button which will launch, the project on the android virtual device, but instead it gave me this error `Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Error running app. Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=exp://192.168.43.148:19000 flg=0x10000000 }`

when i tried running it on my android phone with the expo android app it ran smoothly, i don't know what to do please help thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I got it fixed as follows:

- Go to SDK Manager in `Android studio > SDK Tools` and check whether there is any update for `Android SDK Build-Tools`. If there is any, please make sure you update it.
- Close any Android virtual device currently running and then go to Android Studio Virtual Device Manager and wipe the data of your Android virtual device.
- Make sure you have enough internal storage allocated for your Android virtual device to install apps.
- Check whether Android Debug Bridge utility is installed in your device. If not please install it. To install in mac, I used the below command (Assuming that you have HomeBrew installed in your mac device):

```
brew install android-platform-tools
```

- Start your Android virtual device ( This step should be done before running the expo development server)
- In the `Developer options` menu of your Android virtual device, make sure `USB debugging` option is enabled.
- Finally, try running the development server by `expo start` and press on the button to run on your Android emulator.